# Object into array JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to programming and this problem is bothering me for 3 days straight...

I have a post form on .jsp site for gathering name, surname, mail,... and all this info is saved in object USER. I want to save users in array and display them on the same site. But everytime I use submit button in form new session is created and on array output info is only one user. 
What should I do to solve this problem?
ps: on this stage i can't use sql because it's school projects

```
<% Uporabnik uporabnik = new Uporabnik(); //user
   uporabnik.setIme(request.getParameter("ime"));
   uporabnik.setPriimek(request.getParameter("priimek"));
   uporabnik.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
   uporabnik.setKraj(request.getParameter("kraj"));
   uporabnik.setPostnaStevilka(request.getParameter("postnaStevilka"));

   ArrayList<Uporabnik> seznamUporabnikov = new ArrayList<Uporabnik>(); //array with i want to display
   seznamUporabnikov.add(uporabnik);
   session.setAttribute("seznamUporabnikov", seznamUporabnikov); %>

   <form method="post" action="Registracija.jsp">
     Ime: <input type="text" name="ime"/> <br/>
     Priimek: <input type="text" name="priimek"/> <br/>
     Email: <input type="text" name="email"/> <br/>
     Kraj: <input type="text" name="kraj"/> <br/>
     Postna stevilka: <input type="text" name="postnaStevilka"/> <br/>
     <input type="submit" name="potrdi" value="Vnesi">
     <input type="reset" name="tabelaReset" value="Izbrisi iz tabele">
     <input type="submit" name="resetiraj" value="Izbrisi podatke">
   </form>

   <br/> Seja: <%=session.getAttribute("Oseba")%> <hr/>

   <% if (request.getParameter("potrdi")!=null) {
         session.setAttribute("Oseba", uporabnik);
      } %>
   <% if (request.getParameter("resetiraj")!=null) {
         session.setAttribute("Oseba", null);
      } %>
```

Comment: You keep creating a new array. Instead, retrieve the *existing* array from the session, and add `uporabnik` to the *existing* array.

Comment: Registracija.jsp, may have problem as form submit have url to this jsp

Comment: @AlpeshGediya Or it could be that the OP is creating a new array each time and setting it to the session up there where there's a new array added each time and set into the session.

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes this is also possible,  Hope you don't mind as your surname suggest, are you descent of Sir Issac Newton?

Comment: @AlpeshGediya As far as we can tell, no; we've traced back our ancestry to around that time, so if there's a relationship it's likely to be from significantly before then :)

Comment: @DaveNewton But everytime I subbmit info from form, new session is created so I need to store the session and then retrive it or what? 


Thanks guys for helping, becouse I am dealing with this problem for 20+ hours :(

Comment: No, a new session is not created, unless you're doing something wrong. You're creating a new list; you only need to create the list once, and store it in the session. After that, you *retrieve* the existing session list, and put the days in the *existing* list.

Comment: @DaveNewton what could be wrong in my code if the new session is created every time?

Comment: What makes you think a new session is being created every time?

Comment: @DaveNewton I tested it with <%=session.getAttribute("oseba")%> and everytime I refresh page I get diffrend id ( example: Osebe.Uporabnik@110ed88) and I get same result also when I submit form data

Comment: That's because you keep creating a new list and seeing it into the session, as I've been saying from the beginning.

Comment: @DaveNewton could you please give me an exemple how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @dirtysanchez You already got one in the answer, and I can't really be much more explicit: **stop creating a new list each time and use the one in session. If there isn't one in the session yet, put one there.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after 4 days this stuff works now!!! I am so happy :) anyway.. thank you guys for getting me on the right track...

```
ArrayList<Uporabnik> seznamUporabnikov=null;
//check if already in session before creating.  
if(session.getAttribute("seznamUporabnikov") == null) {        
    seznamUporabnikov = new ArrayList<Uporabnik>(); 
    //array which I want to display
    session.setAttribute("seznamUporabnikov", seznamUporabnikov);   
} else {
    seznamUporabnikov = 
                 (ArrayList<Uporabnik>)session.getAttribute("seznamUporabnikov");
}

if (request.getParameter("potrdi") != null) {
    seznamUporabnikov.add(uporabnik);
}


session.setAttribute("seznamUporabnikov", seznamUporabnikov);
```

Answer (score 0):

change these lines:
`...
 ArrayList seznamUporabnikov = new ArrayList(); //array with i want to display
 seznamUporabnikov.add(uporabnik);
 session.setAttribute("seznamUporabnikov", seznamUporabnikov);
...`
to
`...
 ArrayList seznamUporabnikov=session.getAttribute("seznamUporabnikov");
 if(seznamUporabnikov == null) { //check if already in session before creating.
   ArrayList seznamUporabnikov = new ArrayList(); //array with i want to display
 }
 seznamUporabnikov.add(uporabnik);
 session.setAttribute("seznamUporabnikov", seznamUporabnikov);
...`

Answer (score 0):

create a class and create a static user list under that class and add all users in that list
this list will be available throughout your application lifecycle.

Comment: That only works if they don't want it per-user, and it's synchronized, etc. Until OP states otherwise, it seems like answers should pertain to keeping the list in session. Since the issue is obvious, I don't see any reason to keep in in application scope at this point.